# How to convert RAW8 to RGB8 NSImage

Tags: macos, cocoa, core-image

I'm looking for a way to convert an RAW8 image coming from a camera into a color image NSImage/CIImage.

Is there a framework class that can apply the [Bayer filter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayer_filter) and give me a color RGB image?

I.e. I have an array of bytes with 8bpp and I want a 32bpp RGB NSImage or CIImage.

I tried [CIFilter filterWithImageData](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/QuartzCoreFramework/Classes/CIFilter_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/CIFilter/filterWithImageData%3aoptions%3a) but that makes Xcode stop with EXC_BREAKPOINT?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end I came up with two solutions:

Using OpenCV (http://www.OpenCV.org):

```
    CvMat M = cvMat(height, width, CV_8UC1, frame->image);
    IplImage img; 
    cvGetImage(&M, &img);

    IplImage *copyImg = cvCreateImage(cvSize(width, height), IPL_DEPTH_8U, 3);
    cvCvtColor(&img, copyImg, CV_BayerBG2RGB);
```

But I was missing the obvious: I was getting the image from the camera with libDC1394 and that provides a conversion method itself:

```
    dc1394_debayer_frames(frame, new_frame, DC1394_BAYER_METHOD_NEAREST);
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not go with the obvious solution: ImageIO.framework [can handle RAW images](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/graphicsimaging/Conceptual/ImageIOGuide/imageio_basics/ikpg_basics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40005462-CH216-DontLinkElementID_3).

Comment: Could you give me some more hints? I've enumerated the image types and there are various raw-image types (adobe, sony you name them). I've tried creating a CGImageSourceCreateWithData using these strings as kCGImagSourceTypeIdentifierHint, but no luck. CGImageSourceCreateImageAtIndex(... 0) returns NULL, I cannot query type or count etc. It feels like this can't be the right way, since I don't specify width/height, bpp and the actual bayer pattern.